About the continuity of a set-valued function that appears in the theory of causal stability from Lorentz geometry.
Edit: Nevermind about the abstract formulation that was here at first, user @MoisheKohan gave an easy counterexample. The question is now reformulated to the actual Lorentz geometry problem at hand.

Allow me to explain the concrete problem I'm dealing with first, this will involve some notation and terminology from Lorentz geometry to contextualize. I'm trying to prove a technical result that shows up as a lemma of sorts in the subject of stable causality in general relativity, in a often cited thesis where equivalence of $C^0$-topology and interval topology on the space of conformal Lorentz metrics is proven. This technical result is actually stated without proof (pgs 31-32 here), and all other articles I' ve seen touching the subject cite this source for the overall proof of the equivalence of such topologies.
The actual argument I'm stuck doesn't involve Lorentz geometry directly and can be reinterpreted as a problem of convergence of a certain sequence of sets of compact sets in the Hausdorff metric for the closed sets for a projective space ${P(\mathbb{R}^n)}.$
By $Lor(\mathbb R^n)$ ($n \geq 3$ can be assumed if there is trouble with lower dimensions) I mean the set of non-degenerate, symmetric bilinear forms with index = 1 in $\mathbb R^n$ (scalar products), and $Con(\mathbb R^n$) a quotient space $Lor(\mathbb R^n) / \sim$, where $g \sim h$ iff $g = \lambda h, \lambda > 0$ (a conformal class of scalar products), and elements of $Con(\mathbb R^ n)$ will be denoted with a top bar. One can see that $Lor(\mathbb R^n)$ is open in the vector space of symmetric bilinear forms, and $Con(\mathbb R^n)$ is homeomorphic to an open set of the sphere $\mathbb S^{n(n+1)/2 -1}.$
For $\bar g \in Con(\mathbb R^ n)$ and $g \in \bar g,$ denote the projective lightcone of $\bar g$ as
$$
LC(\bar g) = \{[v] \in P(\mathbb R^n ) : g(v,v) = 0\}
$$
(notice this is independent of representatives for both $\bar g$ and $[v].$) Considering the projective space as a metric space (say as the antipodal equivalence class on a sphere with distance $d([v], [w]) = \min(\|v - w \|,\| v+ w\| )$). I will also denote by $\mathcal H$ the space of nonempty closed sets of $P(\mathbb R^n)$  with Hausdorff distance $d_H.$
The "problematic" statement is that the set-valued function $$\bar g \in Con(\mathbb R^n) \mapsto LC(\bar g) \in \mathcal H$$ is continuous (it is also 1-1, but this one follows since scalar products with same lightcone are in the same conformal class). Intuitively this makes sense, since you would expect very close scalar products to have "very close lightcones" in some sense. For example, ignoring the projective space and the conformal relation for a moment and considering the intersection of usual lightcones with a sphere in three dimensions, making some plots with geogebra these intersections looks like wiggly elipses, so for close scalar products these elipses are very close and you would expect their Hausdorff distance to be small. But I can't see a way to prove this.
What I' ve tried  is, for starters, to use sequencial continuity. Also, since we have a quotient topology $\pi : Lor(\mathbb R^n) \to Con(\mathbb R^ n),$ it suffices to prove continuity of $g \in Lor(\mathbb R^n) \mapsto LC(\bar g) \in \mathcal H,$ and for convergence in $Lor(\mathbb R^n)$ we can use the bilinear operator norm. It also seems more natural here to consider the quadratic form instead of the bilinear form directly, so for $g$  consider
$$ q_g : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R,\quad q_g(v) = g(v,v).$$
The (usual) lightcone of $g$ is then the zero set of $q_g,$ $q_g^{-1}(0).$ By restricting the $q_g$ to the sphere $\mathbb S^{n-1},$ the induced function $\bar q_g : P(\mathbb R^n) \to \mathbb R$ is well defined and continuous with  $\bar q_g ^{-1}(0) = LC(\bar g).$
For a sequence of scalar products $g_k  \to g$ converging in bilinear operator norm,  denoting $q_{g_k} \equiv q_k$ and again restricting these functions to $\mathbb S^{n-1}$   it follows that $q_k|_{\mathbb S^{n-1}} \to q_g|_{\mathbb S^{n-1}}$ uniformly, implying $\bar q_k \to \bar q_g$ uniformly.
This is as far as I got, I can't see any "hard" way of proving this, I've tried some estimatives using the convergence $g_k \to g$ to see if this induces something on $d_H(LC(\bar g_k), LC(\bar g)),$ but the inequalities obtained are not friendly and don't seem meaningful, so ideas to solve the specific problem are very welcome.

Edit: As a failed attempt, at first I wondered if $\bar q_k \to \bar q_g$ uniformly  imples $\bar q_k^{-1}(0) \to \bar q_g^{-1}(0)$ on the Hausdorff metric, so reducing it to the abstract problem

For $(X,d)$ a compact metric space, consider a sequence of continuous functions $f_k: X \to \mathbb R$ converging uniformly to $f: X \to \mathbb R.$ What can we say about the  convergence of the zeros sets $f_k^{-1}(0)$ in Hausdorff distance? Do they converge to $f^{-1}(0)$?

But this is in general false as the comments pointed out, a sequence of constant functions gives an easy counterexample, so other than trying some hard estimative for the distances I can't see way of doing it.

No, such convergence is false in general. All you get is the inclusion $\lim_n[ f_n^{-1}(0)]\subset f^{-1}(0)$, where the limit is understood in Hausdorff metric.

Just think about sequences of constant functions.

@MoisheKohan yes of course, I've been stuck in this problem so long I couldn't think of obvious counterexamples.
